# Writing login information to the keychain failed with error

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, keychain, archlinux

I am used to work in vs code, yesterday I made a fresh **install of arch Linux** in my laptop and today I was trying to log in into vscode to recover my settings and other stuff, when I press on login button it just stand there for around 10 seconds and then shows a dialog with this error:

[Writing login information to the keychain failed with error 'Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.secrets: Timeout was reached'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFXG1.png)

This dialog gives me a [direct link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_troubleshooting-keychain-issues) to solve this kind of issues related with keychain, I tried every of the three solutions that are there but any of them worked for me.

Comment: I wild stab in the dark, but is whatever provides `org.freedesktop.secrets` installed?

Comment: Yes, the provider package for `org.freedesktop.secrets` is `gnome-keyring`, and it is already installed, `gnome-keyring` version gives me `gnome-keyring: 40.0`.  Excuse me if you find yourself in the dark, this is my first question here, I am not sure what should I mention in order to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo pacman -S gnome-keyring
```

Login again and you will not see it [hopefully]!

Comment: This did not work for me